# Is it possible for a thread that is not the UI thread to manipulate the UI elements?

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

I have read that only the UI thread should be allowed to manipulate the UI elements in WinAPI. But I don't think that it is even possible for a thread that is not the UI thread to manipulate the UI elements.

I think that because when a thread (that is not the UI thread) calls the [SendMessage()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx) function to manipulate some UI element, a message will be sent to the UI thread, and then it is the UI thread that will manipulate the UI element and not the other thread.

Am I correct?

Comment: Pretty sure that there are other ways to manipulate UI elements besides calling `SendMessage`.

Comment: Only the thread that creates an `HWND` can receive and dispatch messages for that `HWND`, so all of the *actual* work performed on the `HWND` is done by the owning thread. But other threads can certainly *send* messages to the `HWND`, and they will be dispatched and handled by the owning thread. This is clearly stated in the [`SendMessage()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950.aspx): ...

Comment: ... "*If the specified window was created by a different thread, the system switches to that thread and calls the appropriate window procedure. Messages sent between threads are processed only when the receiving thread executes message retrieval code. The sending thread is blocked until the receiving thread processes the message.*"

Comment: @user3386109 *"Pretty sure that there are other ways to manipulate UI elements besides calling SendMessage."* Can you give examples of these other ways?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau *"But other threads can certainly send messages to the HWND, and they will be dispatched and handled by the owning thread"* Yes this is why I'm asking this question, to know why do some tutorials say that only the UI thread should be allowed to manipulate the UI elements, when in fact it is only the UI thread that is capable to manipulate the UI elements (so even if some other thread wanted to manipulate some UI element, it can't), and other threads can only send the UI thread messages asking it to manipulate the UI elements.

Comment: @PaulMorris from a purely Win32 API perspective, there is not many things that can go wrong with manipulating UI controls across threads, since the API handles serialization for you (not counting race conditions during multi-message operations). Such warnings are usually tied more to *wrapper libraries* that allocate additional resources tied to the UI that are not managed in thread-safe ways, thus making it more dangerous to manipulate across threads.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau *"from a purely Win32 API perspective, there is not many things that can go wrong with manipulating UI controls across threads"* Not sure, but I think that you misunderstood my question, I will clarify it: When a thread that is not the UI thread wants to manipulate a UI control, it uses the `SendMessage()` function to do so, but the `SendMessage()` function is not the one that manipulate the UI control (i.e. it does not manipulate the data structure representing the UI control in memory), but rather it sends a message to the UI thread...

Comment: @Remy Lebeau ...and then the UI thread is the one that will manipulate the data structure representing the UI control in memory, am I correct so far? If I am correct, then it doesn't really make sense to say that other threads can manipulate the UI controls, because it is only the UI thread that can manipulate the UI controls. Am I correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: @PaulMorris from a purely Win32 API perspective, what you say is true, yes. But in modern UI programming, there is a lot more going on than just plain API calls.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Sorry, after re-reading your previous answer, I believe that you did indeed understood my question. When you say: *"Such warnings are usually tied more to wrapper libraries that allocate additional resources tied to the UI that are not managed in thread-safe ways, thus making it more dangerous to manipulate across threads"* You mean for example in C# where each WinAPI UI control object is wrapped in its own C# object, it is not safe to access this C# object from multiple threads?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Just out of curiousity, what if another thread tries to "subclass" the Wndproc of the thread that created the HWND with SetWindowLong? Would Windows block that from happening?

Comment: @Lundin with `SetWindowSubclass()`, yes (it is documented as such). With `SetWindowLong()`, I'm not sure. However, an `HWND` has affinity to its owning thread, and only that thread can receive and dispatch messages to it. So even if you could subclass across threads, messages are still processed only in the context of the owning thread.

Comment: @PaulMorris Can you clarify what you mean by "manipulate UI elements"? Do you mean render them to the window?

Comment: @mnistic I mean by "manipulate UI elements" things like reading some value or setting some value of a UI element (for example: reading the content of a text box or setting the width of a button, etc.), I also mean things like creating a window and destroying a window, etc. So basically I mean any operating that involves a UI element.

Answer (score 2):

First, hypothetically speaking in an attempt to satisfy the OP's curiosity:

- If we define manipulating UI elements as reading from or writing to
  elements' properties, then technically you could come up with your
  own UI framework that would maintain the elements independently from
  the Windows API. Such attempts [have been made](https://github.com/kjk/directui). WPF is one of
  them. You could then theoretically make the framework
  thread-safe and make it possible to access the elements' properties
  from multiple threads.
- Also, GDI allows access to its objects from multiple threads, so you
  could potentially draw to your window from multiple threads (ditto
  for DirectX). WPF for example has a dedicated render thread (or at
  least it used to). You could also specify a different thread to
  process input with [`AttachThreadInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-attachthreadinput).

However, given the premise of the question that we're sticking to using the standard Windows API for creating and managing the UI, it is safe to say that access to the window is only achieved from within the thread that created it, because `SendMessage()` will switch to the owner thread. But that's not to say that invoking `SendMessage()` from multiple threads is a safe or a recommended approach. On the contrary, it is fraught with peril and care would have to be taken to properly synchronize the threads.

For one thing, a typical `WndProc()` looks like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    ...
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_MYMSG1:
            ...
            SendMessage(hWnd, WM_MYMSG2, wParam, lParam);
            ...
        break;
        ...    
    }
    ...
}
```

So in order to protect your `WndProc()` so it can be accessed from multiple threads, you would have to make sure to use a reentrant lock, and not a semaphore, for example.

Secondly, if you use a reentrant lock you must make sure that it is only used within `WndProc()` or even make it specific to a message. Otherwise it is very easy to get into a deadlock:

```
//Worker thread:
void foo () 
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&g_cs);
    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_MYMSG1, NULL, NULL);
    LeaveCriticalSection(&g_cs); 
} 

//Owner thread:
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_MYMSG1:
        {
            EnterCriticalSection(&g_cs); //Deadlock!
            ...
            LeaveCriticalSection(&g_cs); 
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Thirdly, you would have to make sure not to invoke any control-yielding functions within your `WndProc()`; these [include but are not limited to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues#message-deadlocks): `DialogBox()`, `MessageBox()` and `GetMessage()`. Else you get a deadlock.

Then, consider a multi-window application, with each window's message pump being run in a separate thread. You would have to ensure not to send any messages between the threads in order not to end up with a deadlock:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    ...
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_MYMSG1:
            ...
            SendMessage(hWnd2, WM_MYMSG1, wParam, lParam); //Deadlock!
            ...
        break;
        ...    
    }
    ...
}
```

You would also have to be very careful with using Windows APIs that implicitly manage the operating system's process-specific locks, and [preserve and maintain the proper lock hierarchy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Win7AppQual/preventing-hangs-in-windows-applications). Quite a few User32 functions and many blocking COM calls fall into this category.

Some of these issues may be alleviated by using [`InSendMessage()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644941%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [`ReplyMessage()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644948(v=vs.85).aspx) (when using `SendMessage()`) or  `PostMessage()` and its siblings. However then you get into all kinds of control flow issues, because you may want to know that the message was processed before continuing the current thread or processing the next message. So you end up having to implement some kind of a synchronization mechanism anyway, but this becomes increasingly difficult with many pitfalls to avoid.

Problems don't stop with just sending messages between threads either. Changing `WndProc()` from a different thread can lead to [terrible race-condition bugs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20051010-09/?p=33843):

```
//in UI thread:
wpOld = (WNDPROC)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC);
//in another thread:
SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)otherWndProc);
//back in UI thread:
SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)newWndProc);
//still in UI thread:
LRESULT CALLBACK newWndProc(...)
{
    CallWindowProc(wpOld, ...); //Wrong wpOld!
}
```

Also, improperly using DCs from multiple threads can [lead to subtle bugs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20051011-10/?p=33823).

These reasons, and others (including performance), may have led the designers of standard API wrappers like MFC and WinForms to simply assume that their APIs will be used in a single-thread context. They don't offer any thread-safety protections and it's up to the user to implement such mechanisms, however the higher level of abstraction makes it [even easier](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b85127aa-3860-413a-b71c-d3664dc3222e/waitforsingleobject-deadlock-in-mfc-event-handler?forum=vcmfcatl) to [neglect the underlying issues](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?282773-SendMessage-PostMessage-amp-Threads). When such problems arise, usually the answer is: don't use the control from outside the owner thread.